# Map array function not displaying contents

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Based on what I've learned from trial, if you have a conditional surrounding a map array method, you need a return statement to display the results, but if there is no conditional statement, you don't need this.  However, I'm a bit confused on why the following map array method isn't displaying my content.

```
{match &&
    match.params.invoiceNum === undefined &&
    invoices.map(item => {
        return (
            <ListItem key={item.id}>
                <Folder>
                    <i className='medium material-icons'>folder</i>
                </Folder>
                <Item to={`/Employer Invoices/${item.id}`}>{item.id}</Item>
            </ListItem>
        );
    })}
```

Also, all needed code is available above this snippet.

Comment: could you try surrounding match && match.params.... with parantheses closing before the second &&

Comment: Heh, my ESLint filter removes them.  I guess they are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 cases where you don't display any data

## 1 - It never reaches the `.map`

Maybe `match && match.params.invoiceNum === undefined` is never true and you never reaches `.map`.

## 2 - `invoices` is a empty array

If `invoices` is a empty array (`[]`), `.map` will never run and won't display any data.

Do some `console.log`in `invoices` to make sure that it isn't an empty array.

Comment: I removed the debugger and console statements when posting to this thread.  It's definitely making it through the block of code, just not outputting the results.

Comment: @pingeyeg add `console.log` inside `.map` function and see if it shows something

Comment: Yes, the following is being returned and it's an object array
`{id: "112", months: Array(2)}
{id: "113", months: Array(2)}
{id: "114", months: Array(2)}
{id: "115", months: Array(2)}`

Comment: @pingeyeg Test this: replace all components that are returned inside of `.map` to something static like `return (<h1>ITS WORKING</h1>)` . If you see the `h1`, the problem isn't with `.map` but the components you use that don't render anything.

Comment: It only returns when I remove both the match and match.params... from the block, but I need those.

Comment: If adding the  `console.log` you see the data, this means that `.map` is working and the reason why you don't see anything there is nothing to do with `.map`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `match &&
    match.params.invoiceNum === undefined &&
    match.params.invoices.map(...)` ? Maybe you are forgetting `match.params` before `invoices.map`

Comment: So, invoices is a variable containing data coming from the store within redux.  I'm using react router to grab the match property to work on whether something should be displayed or not.

Comment: `It only returns when I remove both the match and match.params` maybe it never reaches `.map` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196582/discussion-between-pingeyeg-and-vencovsky).

Comment: Anyone else have other thoughts?